# can not find the error in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code takes in an input of the form:
a b
c
Where a is the number of rows of chairs, b is the number of chairs per row, and c is the number of people attending.
I need to output in the form:
d e
Where d is the number of people who can sit, and e is the number of people who will be forced to stand.
There may be more people than seats, or vice versa, and there may be the perfect amount, but I need to calculate it. Here is my code to do this, can you help me find my bug, it is failing some test cases.

lines is a list containing the input
lines[0] is the first line
lines[1] is the second

```
lines[0] = lines[0].rstrip().split()
seats = int(lines[0][0]) * int(lines[0][1])
if seats <= int(lines[1]):
    standing = int(lines[1]) - seats
    sitting = seats
else:
    standing = 0
    sitting = int(lines[1])
```

Comment: Please post the error, and write down `lines`.

Comment: But there's already something confusing. lines is a list of lists ? or a list of ints ?

`seats = int(lines[0][0]) * int(lines[0][1])`  so lines is a list of list
`if seats <= int(lines[1]): ` lines is a list of ints ?

Comment: As @madjaoue said, please `print(lines)` and post your error

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to modify `lines`

```
lines[0] = lines[0].rstrip().split()
```

To calculate your number of seats, you just need to multiply `lines[0]` by `lines[1]`

```
seats = int(lines[0]) * int(lines[1])
```

And, your number of people attending is in `lines[2]` not in `lines[1]`

```
standing = int(lines[2]) – seats
```

Full code

```
lines = ['5', '5', '30']
seats = int(lines[0]) * int(lines[1])
if seats <= int(lines[2]):
    standing = int(lines[2]) - seats
    sitting = seats
else:
    standing = 0
    sitting = int(lines[2])

print "sitting : " + str(sitting)
print "standing : " + str(standing)
```

Result :

```
sitting : 25
standing : 5
```